# GSuite Sheets addon not launching

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I've published a private sheets addon for my company, but unfortunately when I try to run it both onInstall and onOpen fail with no execution logs and a 0s execution time in the Apps Script Console. It works fine from the sheet associated with the script project, just not from anywhere else. All I have to go on is an error in the chrome console:

`Google Apps Script: We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED.`

Here are the relevant functions:

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
  Logger.log("Installed")
  // Perform additional setup as needed.
}

function onOpen(e) {
    Logger.log("Opening...")
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createAddonMenu()
        .addItem("Launch", "run")
        .addToUi()
    Logger.log("Added menu items")
}
```

None of the logger messages are actually logged, making me think that the function is never being launched despite the execution showing up in the console.

[image: Console logs]

Any tips on how to debug/track down the error would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I've also tried testing it via the script editor with AuthMode.NONE and AuthMode.LIMITED. Both work fine. I only encounter the error when running after installing via the GSuite Marketplace.

Here is the manifest.json:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION\_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230776/were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-while-reading-from-storage-error-code-perm)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried both solutions listed there but no change.

Comment: The way you write logs to Stack Driver is by using `console.log("Something to log")`. If you use `Logger` class, those logs will only be visible from the editor, and get deleted after each run. And please provide a copy of your "manifest.json" file

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be working now. I changed the timeZone in manifest.json to America/Los_Angeles (my local tz) and re-published and all errors are gone. Not sure if this change is what made the difference or not, but thanks to Aerials for the nudge to look there.

Edit: This may also have been related to my use of clasp deployments. The problem recurred for me after modifying the script. I created a new deployment via the script editor UI (Publish -> Publish from manifest) and then clicked the "install addon" next to the new version. I also updated the Gsuite marketplace listing to point at the new version, and everything seems to be working.

Comment: It's unlikely that changing the time zone was what fixed the problem.