# google.script.run not working on Chrome Browser for some users

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Sheets Add-on is erroring on Chrome when running a google.script.run.myFunction(). It runs correctly on Safari and Firefox and an exact copy of the project on another google user account also runs correctly.

Console error message just says `uncaught` as per the following screenshot:

[image]

No error is caught by adding .withFailureHandler() and the execution logs don't show the google.script.run as being run

Comment: 1. Catch the error with `.withFailureHandler()` 2. Check  script editor>view> executions for timestamps, and whether it correlates with when the user triggered `google.script.run` and for any other errors. [Edit] your question with such debugging details.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764900 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763018

Comment: Thank you. Adding the logging from the first link exposed the error - is the issue as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230776/were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-while-reading-from-storage-error-code-perm (logged in to multiple google accounts). Disabling App Script V8 runtime resolves.

Comment: I thought you said `FailureHandler()` didn't catch it.  What logging do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is as described here [We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230776/were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-while-reading-from-storage-error-code-perm) (logged in to multiple google accounts). Disabling App Script V8 runtime resolves.