# How can I make this work run from the Client Side

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have exhausted all possible permutations I could possibly try, like moving all of the .js code into the html, but the functions would not run from the doc' sidebar, in every run -click any of those buttons- I have to go back to the script's editor to run the sidebar. The script for functions I embedded in my html is:

```js
function Check() {
  google.script.run.results_run();
}

function Clear() {
  google.script.run.results_clear();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="c-btn c-btn--primary" onclick="javascript:Check();"> Check </button> 
<a class="clear-highlights" onclick="javascript:Clear();">Clear highlights</a>
```

[image: Doc's AddOn]

Comment: How are you calling the functions? (please include a [mcve]) Also, add more details about your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask] (they can be brief but should be more descriptive)

Comment: Please [edit] the question.

Comment: ```
<button type="button" class="c-btn c-btn--primary" onclick="javascript:Check();">
              Check
            </button>

            <a class="clear-highlights" onclick="javascript:Clear();">Clear highlights</a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    
    <script>
    function Check(){
    google.script.run.results_run();
    }

    function Clear(){
    google.script.run.results_clear();
    }
    </script>
```
From my html

Comment: Thanks Ruben, I'm new to this.

Comment: `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).results_run();`

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `javascript:` from `onclick="javascript:Check();"` and from `onclick="javascript:Clear();"` as it's not needed. Better if you use an event listener instead of inline JavaScript.
2. When using `google.script.run` use `withSuccessHandler` and `withFailureHandler` .

```
function Check() {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(){
    // if needed do something  when the server side function runs succesfully
  })
  .withFailureHandler(function(error){
    // if an error occurss on server side log the error into the console
    console.error(error.message,error.stack);
    
  }).results_run();
}

function Clear() {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(){
    // if needed do something  when the server side function runs succesfully
  })
  .withFailureHandler(function(error){
    // if an error occurss on server side log the error into the console
    console.error(error.message,error.stack);
    
  }).results_clear();
}
```

3. Review the script execution page, there might be logged a server-side error.
4. Try disabling the new runtime (Chrome V8)

Resources

- [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Related

- [How can I make this work run from the Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63971833/1595451)
- [google.script.run not working on Chrome Browser for some users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63681202/1595451)